# DOM exception when using notification API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am working in chrome extension and I want to use a notification API to alert when an event occur, but when I write to code of notification, DOM exception occurs.

```
 var description="10 minustes are last for your "+nextItem.noteDesc+" event";
alert(description);
if ( window.webkitNotifications) {
  console.log("Notifications are supported!");
    webkitNotifications.createNotification(
       'http://aux3.iconpedia.net/uploads/634295872704029736.png', 
          'Alert!', description);
}
else {
 console.log("Notifications are not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.");
}
```

I make the request for notification permission in mainfest.json file

```
{
 "name": "Alert extention",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Personal alert.",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "img/clock.png",
"popup": "Alert.html"
 },
  "permissions": [
   "notifications"
]  
}
```

this sentence "Notifications are supported!" is printed on console, then this error occur

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit**
Note: The browser I use is google chrome .

Comment: Please edit your answer if you want to provide additional information. Not everybody reads all the comments...

Comment: When you install your extension, does Chrome confirm with you that it's okay to give the extension notification permissions? If not, that tells us there's a problem with your manifest file and/or installation.

Comment: No, it doesn't ask me for permission.

Comment: There you go, then, that's what you need to debug. It's not the code, it's the installation.

Comment: Actually @T.J.Crowder, that is incorrect. Users are not warned about the "notifications", as well as some others. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html#nowarning

Comment: BTW, I was making huge mistake, I was testing the chrome extension as it's a web application, becouse of that I can see the JS console, when I reload the extension and test it, no notication occur, but I don't know how to see the warning or errors occur, since I can't open to console when chrome extension is running?!

Comment: First of all, can I suggest removing the `window.webkitNotifications` check completely? Since you are making an extension for Chrome (a browser which supports and defined the `webkitNotifications` API) you clearly do not require this guard. Finally, what context is this code being called in (e.g. background page, options page, popup, context)?

Comment: I declare that in manifest.json file it's popup

Comment: @Alasdair, I remove it and the same ! but how can I see if an error occur in chrome-extension?

Comment: To debug and develop extensions go to chrome://extensions and enable "Developer mode" in the top right corner. Now, if you click a page listed under your extension you can view the Developer Tools (including console). Popups can be debugged by right-clicking the browser action button and selecting "Inspect Popup". Also, to install your extension under development ensure that you click "Load unpacked extension..." and select the directory containing your manifest.json file.

Comment: When I make right-click on the button in chrome extension no menu appears?

Comment: Are you sure Developer mode is enabled? Is there a plus (+) sign to its left? Even without developer mode, you should see be able to access the right-click on extension buttons. I'll post some links in an answer for you.

Comment: No there's (-) sign to the right of chrome->extension -> developer mode.

Comment: Then click it and make it a plus (+).

Comment: @Alasdair: Nice one, I didn't realize that about the notifications permission.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

As revealed in the comments for the question the problem originates from a lack of understanding on developing and testing Chrome extensions.

I highly recommend reading through the following official documentation;

- [Tutorial: Getting Started](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)
- [Tutorial: Debugging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html)

Also, that [whole site](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html) should be any Chrome extension developers first call for documentation and guides.